# How can I make a table view controller that has cells smaller than the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make a table view controller with cells that have a small margin on all sides, and overlay a background image. The tutorials on Google that I found do not cover making a background for the whole view and making the individual cells have margins.

Here is a rough example from Scoutmob of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: One of Scoutmob's more recent design themes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do it would probably be to resize the UITableViewCell's `contentView`, `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` inside `layoutSubviews`.

e.g:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    const CGRect insetRect            = CGRectInset( self.bounds, 10, 10 );

    self.contentView.frame            = insetRect;
    self.backgroundView.frame         = insetRect;
    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = insetRect;
}
```

If you want to use an image background, set the `backgroundView` to a UIImageView.

Using this method allows you to support rotation, as well as reorder and delete controls and all the other stuff UITableView does to its cells (don't forget to add your subviews to the cell's `contentView` and not directly to its view).

Comment: This is a better solution. +1.

Comment: Do you know if the background image will stretch to fill, or if it should be the same pixel size as the screen? (And does there need to be a img.png and img@2x.png?)

Comment: The background image would be the cell's background image. Since you'd be putting it inside a UIImageView, you could set the stretch parameters as you like.

Yes, you should have @2x versions of every bitmap image you use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example of what you are looking for. Both margin between cells and overlay an Image.
It uses custom tableview cell and placed subviews with margin. It has example projects for both Storyboard and Xib based files

https://github.com/Seitk/FB-Gallery

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to set the background view:

`tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundImage.png"]];`

As for the "space" in between cells, simply make a new `UIView` to act as a container. Then, insert your smaller content into the middle of the view as a subview. Then, set the height of the table view cell appropriately and add the container view as a subview. The effect will be the "picture frame" type look you posted in your question.

Alternatively, you can just add every cell to the table view in its own section, which will have a similar effect.